# The Location finder component does not fire auto completion on overlay + SXA 1.9 and Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sxa

I have to build locate the Branch/ATM feature using SXA 1.9 in Sitecore 9.2. I have used below components to achieve the same but, have few questions.

**Components used for Listing:**

Location Finder

Filter Drop-down(SXA Tags - Branch/ATM)

Search Results

**Components used for Details Page:**

Page Content

Map

**Couple of issues:**

1. Adding the same location finder component with same datasource in Overlay does not fire the autocomplete search.
2. How to set the current location on the location finder. I see mixed mode on the control properties but don't see any button to set the current location.
3. I have dropped the Radius filter and able to see the results based on distance filter selected but how to set the default radius without displaying the component?
4. Is there a way to pass some details from Search Results to Overlay like Branch name and address i would like to show on overlay that is opening on clicking of the link in search result?
5. I see the longitude and latitude deprecated from the iPOI template and see there is /sitecore/templates/System/Geospatial/Coordinate template which is internally used by all the components that i have used. Do i need inherit my branch template using POI or Coordinate template?
6. For the detail page to display the Map i have two ways to deal with.

   a. Create all the Branch and ATM related locations and map the POI to the Map

   b. Just Define the central point long and lat on the Map and point the same
   Which one will be the best approach and is there any issue with iPOI deprecating in future releases.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have asked too many questions, Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please limit your posts to a single question. For questions that might require discussion, you can use the [Community Forums](https://community.sitecore.net/) or [Sitecore Slack](https://sitecore.chat).

Comment: Sure Richard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This might be a bug. Do you have any console errors?
2. The current location should be set (`g` parameter in the browser hash) by the browser in the mixed mode. Keep in mind that you need to enable this in your browser, Chrome for some reason is blocking location requests.
3. There is no way to specify the default radius in Radius Filter. But can think about custom script which will update browser hash.
4. No. This requires custom implementation.
5. I have no idea what `Coordinate` is. You should be inheriting from `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Geospatial/IPoi`.
6. Sorry, but I don't understand what is your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 

1. I will have the support ticket raised for this issue. 

2. I did enable the location in chrome settings but, still not working. Is there anything else i need to configure on control other than Mixed mode?

5. The search and filtering  happening on Conordinate (long and lat) and the IPoi is marked as deprecated. 

6. I want to use the map on the search result detail view. I have added map in page data with long and lat defined central point which doesn't show any pin. 
Can i create all locations under data and assign POI to map?